# Is there any way to integrate reactjs with postgres for creating dynamic dependent dropdown?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql

[image]Am new to reactjs and am creating a form in reactjs with the use of postgresql. 
I've established connection between postgres and node.js and got values in the first dropdown.

I want to get values corresponding to the first dropdown in second dropdown from the same table in the database. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve it.

```
<select name="fruits" value={this.state.data.fruit}>
    {this.fruitData.map((e, key) => {
        return <option key={key} value={e.value}>{e.fruit_name}</option>;
    })}
</select>
```

I have attached the screenshot of database and required output[image: This is the required output]:

Comment: What is your data looking like ?  What output do you want ?

Comment: You need to show us your database structure, and what exact result you want, the code you have tried so far(these two lines of code you have added in question makes no sense), what results are are you getting and errors if any.

Comment: Hi @Treycos , I've updated the question with the screenshots of the database and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have specific options in the second dropdown, based on what was selected in the first dropdown (like showing cities based on a country selected) then you can monitor your first selection as a value in the component's state and then handle changes in the componentDidUpdate function like so.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(this.state.country !== prevState.country) {
        this.setState((state, props) => ({
          filteredCities: props.cities.filter(city => city.country === state.country)
        }))
    }
}
```

Then you can use the state value of filteredCities (or whatever you are filtering) in your second drop-down to do a map just like you did with fruitData, producing all of your dependent options.